# Run subprocess in thread and stop it

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to run a python file with another python file in threading with subprocess. I am able to run the file, but not able to stop it.

##### What I want is

> I want to **run** the `test.py` with my `main.py` in *thread* and stop it by entering `stop` in the console.

#### `test.py`

```py
import time

while True:
    print("Hello from test.py")
    time.sleep(5)
```

#### `main.py`

```py
import subprocess
import _thread

processes = []

def add_process(file_name):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python", file_name], shell=True)
    processes.append(p)
    print("Waiting the process...")
    p.wait()

while True:
    try:
        # user input
        ui = input("> ")

        if ui == "start":
            _thread.start_new_thread(add_process, ("test.py",))
            print("Process started.")
        elif ui == "stop":
            if len(processes) > 0:
                processes[-1].kill()
                print("Process killed.")
        else:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting Program!")
        break
```

#### Output

```
C:\users\me>python main2.py
> start
Process started.
> Waiting the process...
Hello from test.py, after 0 seconds
Hello from test.py, after 4 seconds

> stop
Process killed.
> Hello from test.py, after 8 seconds
Hello from test.py, after 12 seconds
    
> stopHello from test.py, after 16 seconds

Process killed.
> Hello from test.py, after 20 seconds

>
```

#### The program is still running even after I stop it with `kill` function, I have tried `terminate` also. I need to stop that, how can I. Or, is there any alternative module for subprocess to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have just started multiple processes.  What happens if you replace your stop code with this:

```py
for proc in processes:
    proc.kill()
```

This should kill them all.

Note that you are on windows, and on windows [`terminate()` is an alias for `kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill).  It is not a good idea to rely on killing processes gracelessly anyway, and if you need to stop your `test.py` you would be better off having some means of communicating with it and having it exit gracefully.

Incidentally, you don't want `shell=True`, and you're better off with `threading` than with `_thread`.

Comment: the for loop did not help, but that `"Incidentally, you don't want shell=True"` just saved my day! Thank you so much.

Comment: So, the answer is `"shell=True"` prevents the app from being killed.

Comment: Windows processes are quite hard to kill sometimes (hence the updated note about terminate()).  I suspect spawning a subshell was somehow making the OS think the process was more important; goodness knows why.  On linux I have no difficulty terminating or killing a process with shell=True or not.